# Rode NT1-A into Audient iD4 mkII clipping problem

Tags: audio-interfaces, vocals, clipping, rode

I am having an issue where my rode NT1-A into Audient iD4 mkII starts clipping at low volume.
When im recording vocals and the volume reaches -6db, the audio saturates. Is this normal? I find this strange since i've used USB condensers before which are more resilient to clipping than this.
I'm guessing the issue lies after the microphone in the signal chain, since the saturation can be countered with lower gain levels on the interface input, this does however mean that the recorded audio will be very quiet.
If anybody has any idea of what i could try to do to fix this, or at least diagnose the issue, that would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you measuring your -6dB? That's it's neatly at -6 makes me wonder if you're coming into a stereo channel with a 6dB pan law, making your mono source actually 6dB louder than it appears.